# Using regex to grab only digits or the decimal separator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I have the following piece of code to grab the amount and another amount.

```
@payer_contract_params['payer'] = JSON.parse(@payer_contract_params['payer'])
@payer_contract_params['amount'] = @payer_contract_params['amount'].to_s.tr('$', '').tr(',','')
@payer_contract_params['stoploss_amount'] = @payer_contract_params['stoploss_amount'].to_s.tr('$', '').tr(',','')
```

It works, but it will only work in locales which use '$' as the currency and ',' as a separator. How could I Use regex to grab grab only digits or the decimal separator?

Answer (score 0):

Use gsub like this `@payer_contract_params['amount'].to_s.gsub(/[^\d,]/, '')`

This will replace all characters that are not digits or comma.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple

```
/(^\d+$)|(^\.$)/
```

Breakdown

`()` - Indicates a capturing group

`^` - Indicates the regex starts with the following expression

`\d` - Matches any digit

`+` - Mathes 1 or more of the previous selector

`$` - Indicates the regex ends with the previous expression

`|` - Or

`\.` - Matches a period. Note the slash to escape it.

Comment: This will match a string that is only digits or the string `"."`. I suspect that's not what you intended.

Answer (score -1):

You can calculate your regex's in Ruby here at http://rubular.com/